# Adding ListFragment dynamically on android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make an android layout where I have ListFragment on the left of the screen that contains menu entries and then an area to the right of the ListFragment where I can programmatically load in different fragments based on the entry selected on the left. So I started off by making an xml layout file that has a horizontal linear layout which contains two frame layouts. My thought was that I could load my fragments into the frame layouts.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_left"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="30"/>


    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_right"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="70"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then in my MainViewActivity class in the onCreate method I add a list fragment to the left container, and a list fragment to the right container.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu_items);

    if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_left) != null) {
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            MenuListFragment menuListFragment = new MenuListFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container_left, menuListFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    } 

    if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_right) != null) {
        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            MoveListFragment moveListFragment = new MoveListFragment();
            FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container_right, moveListFragment);
            ft.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

So then the onCreate method of the MenuListFragment is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
            R.array.menu_items, R.layout.main_menu_item));
}
```

And then the onCreate method of the MoveListFragment is:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    String[] items = { "move 1", "move 2", "move 3", "move 4" };
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.move_list_items, items));
}
```

and here is the main_menu_item xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="6dp" 
    android:id="@+id/main_menu_item"/>
```

and move_list_items xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:padding="6dp" 
    android:id="@+id/move_list_item"/>
```

When I run this code, I do not get any errors of any kind, but nothing but a white background shows up on the screen. I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Calling `findViewById(R.id.fragment_container_left)` will give you the FrameLayout, not the fragment, which obviously will never be null. You should check whether the respective fragment already exists using `findFragmentById`:

```
if(getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container_left) == null) {
        MenuListFragment menuListFragment = new MenuListFragment();
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container_left, menuListFragment);
        ft.commit();
}
```

As another heads up, you can link the the content fragment with the list fragment using `setTargetFragment` on the list fragment. This will automatically reconnect the fragments should the fragments be recreated.